# Angularjs Ng-repeat with search filter only works on 2nd character keyup

Tags: angularjs, html

I have implemented basic Angularjs search filter but it only work when I enter 2nd character in input box.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" class="search-input" id="search-input"><div ng-repeat="x in publishList | filter:search"></div>
```

Comment: How many items are you searching through?

Comment: [ {
      "scheduleName":"Forrest",
   },
   {
      "scheduleName":"Gump",
   },
   {
      "scheduleName":"saw",
   },
   {
      "scheduleName":"xmen",
   },
   {
      "scheduleName":"troy",
   }
]

Comment: suppose I try to search "r" then in this case "saw" should not show but it still showing. But when I type "re" then it is working fine and only showing the "Forrest".

Comment: Try entering "G" and then wait. You should now only see Gump. If not come back agian. 

One problem that can be is if you enter "e" because then you have 2 instances of "e" occuring.

Comment: tried the above one. not working. Please refer my above given example.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the same and is working, not sure why it is not working for you.
How ever can you try this?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.scheduleName" class="search-input" id="search-input">
```

Comment: have you tried with the example which I have shared with McBoman ?

Comment: I have just updated my answer, can you try this as here you want to search based on property scheduleName and in the filter, you will have to pass the search object similar to your object of your publish list.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with the code and the array you've given and it works for me.

Could you create a jsfiddle or plnkr example illustrating the problem ?

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
  
  function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.items = [
    { scheduleName : 'Forrest' },
    { scheduleName : 'Gump' },
    { scheduleName : 'saw' },
    { scheduleName : 'xmen' },
    { scheduleName : 'troy' }
    ];
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.search"/>
    <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items | filter : ctrl.search">
      {{item.scheduleName}}
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

You can also filter by an object's property in the array by using any one of the two approaches given below.

Specifying the property to filter in the AngularJS built-in filter called *filter*.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
  
  function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.items = [
    { id: 1, scheduleName : 'Forrest' },
    { id: 2, scheduleName : 'Gump' },
    { id: 3, scheduleName : 'saw' },
    { id: 4, scheduleName : 'xmen' },
    { id: 5, scheduleName : 'troy' }
    ];
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.search"/>
    <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items | filter : { scheduleName: ctrl.search }">
      {{item.id}}. {{item.scheduleName}}
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Specifying an object to be used to filter - this is more dynamic.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);
  
  function DefaultController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.items = [
    { id: 1, scheduleName : 'Forrest' },
    { id: 2, scheduleName : 'Gump' },
    { id: 3, scheduleName : 'saw' },
    { id: 4, scheduleName : 'xmen' },
    { id: 5, scheduleName : 'troy' }
    ];
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.search.scheduleName"/>
    <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items | filter : ctrl.search">
      {{item.id}}. {{item.scheduleName}}
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```